# browser close not triggering the visibilityChange on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, visibilitychange

I am trying to save some statistics when the user closes the browser, below is the code

```
    if (typeof document.hidden !== 'undefined') { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support
      hidden = 'hidden';
      visibilityChange = 'visibilitychange';
    } else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== 'undefined') {
      hidden = 'mozHidden';
      visibilityChange = 'mozvisibilitychange';
    } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
      hidden = 'msHidden';
      visibilityChange = 'msvisibilitychange';
    } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== 'undefined') {
      hidden = 'webkitHidden';
      visibilityChange = 'webkitvisibilitychange';
    } else {
      console.log('in else condition');
    }

if (typeof document.addEventListener === 'undefined' || hidden === undefined) {
      console.log("App requires a browser, such as Google Chrome or Firefox, that supports the Page Visibility API.");
    } else {
      document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);
    }

 function handleVisibilityChange() {
// Send a ajax call with **async: false**
}
```

The above code works well in mozilla firefox, google chrome but does not in safari. I am testing this on Mac Os and safari version is `Version 12.1.1 (14607.2.6.1.1)`

Can any please suggest if this is an expected behaviour in safari and what could be done as a workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MDN docs, the "pagehide" event should work for this:

> If you're specifically trying to detect page unload events, the pagehide event is the best option.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event

Comment: Also, you may be able to use navigator.sendBeacon instead of an AJAX call for better performance.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event#sending_end-of-session_analytics_on_transitioning_to_hidden